# classic asp nested loop sql query why is the following occuring

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

I am getting confused now and would be happy if someone could assist me here
i want the selected values from table1 to be displayed with the values of table2
but instead of only getting 3 records out for sql2 the output for table2 gives me the same 3 records.

If I enter both queries in sql analyzer it works fine. Goal is to get the output of
sql1 and sql1 using  classic asp in 3 lines, one loop:

```
line1 rs("firstname") & space(1) & rs("boss")
line2 rs("firstname") & space(1) & rs("boss")
line3 rs("firstname") & space(1) & rs("boss")
```

procedure: I first have to do a query (sql1) after that (sql2) which is depended on the 
outcome of sql1

```
table1
id| |user| |firstname| |lastname| |acc|
1    user1   firstname1  lastname1 loc1
2    user2   firstname2  lastname2 loc2
3    user3   firstname3  lastname3 loc3
4    user4   firstname4  lastname4 loc1
5    user5   firstname5  lastname5 loc1

table2
id| |boss| |first_name| |username|
1     boss1  boss1email   user1 
2     boss2  boss2email   user2 
2     boss3  boss3email   user3
2     boss4  boss4email   user4
2     boss5  boss5email   user5

sql="select * from table1 where acc='loc1'"
Set rs=dbcon.Execute(sql)
do until rs.EOF
Response.Write rs("firstname")


Set rs1 = server.CreateObject ("adodb.recordset")
sql2="Select * from table2 where username='user1'"
set rs1=dbcon.execute(sql2)
do until rs1.eof

response.write rs1("boss")

rs1.movenext
loop

rs.movenext
loop<
```

Comment: I would expect 5 records given your data. How many do you get?

Comment: thx for your comment but I wrote wrong. I meant for table2 i get the same 3 records .

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
SELECT t1.firstname, t2.boss FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.user = t2.username
WHERE t1.acc ="loc1"
```

Comment: I understand what that means but I would like to know how I could modify my currrent code and achieve it in classic asp. The goal is not too get the same records instead of 3 different rows for the output of table2.

Comment: first, I am not versed in asp Classic, i use the .net family.  Could you do something like this:

    sql="SELECT WITH JOIN HERE"
    Set rs=dbcon.Execute(sql)
    do until rs.EOF
    Response.Write rs("firstname") & ("boss")"

Comment: ok thank you for your feedback . I have resolved it by using the view functionality in sql

Answer (score 0):

I have used the view function and saved it and use asp to call it.

Comment: If this is an answer that solved your problem please make it more clear otherwise if it's just additional details please add this to your existing question and delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that in your code you need to replace in this line

```
sql2="Select * from table2 where username='user1'"
```

the 'user1' with som kind of reference to rs("username"). With the code you have you would get the same record from table2 for each record of table1.